# Using AWK to print lines between patterns after a pattern has been met

Tags: regex, printing, awk, conditional-statements

I am trying to print specific parts of a file that looks like this:

```
99999 1 55 127
{bunch of numbers here}
99999 2 55 126
{bunch of numbers here}
99999 3 55 144
{bunch of numbers here}
```

and basically I am trying to print the "bunch of numbers" (along with the preceeding line) when a specific sequence is met. The `99999` is always constant and i dont care about the number right after, but i want to condition the next two numbers.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{}
{
    if ( $3 == 55 && $4 = 100 )
    {next
     do{print $0}
      while($1 != 99999}
}}
END{}
```

I'm quite new to `awk` and would really appreciate the help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear to me...

I guess you want to print out block of lines after (inclusive) a `99999 x 55 100` and before (exclusive) another `99999 ...` line.

I used your example, (btw, you should provide a better example and with output.) but I changed your criteria to `$3==55 and $4=126` so that the block sits in the middle of your data.

```
 awk '$1==99999{f=($3==55&&$4==126)?1:0}f' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
99999 1 55 127
{bunch of numbers here}
1
2
99999 2 55 126
3
4
{bunch of numbers here}
99999 3 55 144
5
6
{bunch of numbers here}

kent$  awk '$1==99999{f=($3==55&&$4==126)?1:0}f' f   
99999 2 55 126
3
4
{bunch of numbers here}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag, set it when either third and fourth field match, and reset it (exiting) when found next line that its first field is `99999`:

```
awk '
    $1 == 99999 && flag == 1 { exit } 
    $3 == 55 && $4 == 126 { flag = 1 } 
    flag == 1 { print }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
99999 2 55 126
{bunch of numbers here}
```